# Reinstalling wamp server

Tags: windows, wamp

I have my wampserver installed on `D:\wamp`. Will i still be able to run wamp after i format `c:\` (windows drive) ONLY?

If NOT, what are the options to keep my old `php.ini` settings and databases? 
    Is backup of old wamp folder, which I replace after the format an option?

I really dont want to dump all of my databases and rewrite al `php.ini` settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that wamp servers - mysql, apache etc are installed as services and even if they are'nt chances are that wamp won't work after reinstalling the OS. You should make a backup copy your php.ini and backup your mysql databases. I use mysqldum for backing up mysql.